# how to add a new post type and fetch all the post related to it in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add  a new post type  for example news in the admin and get the post related to it . How can we do it in wordpress? Do i have to add a plugin ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for `register_post_type()` and `register_taxonomy()`. Then you can use query_posts:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR POST TYPE',
    'taxonomy' => 'YOUR TAXONOMY FOR THE POST TYPE', 
    'terms' => $array_of_categories,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```